# Is there a way with shelf to get the address of the caller?

Tags: dart

I need to get the address of the caller i'm not able to find how to do it.

I have looked in the context but there is anything.

Is this possible ?

**EDIT**: I have found see the response below

Answer (score 3):

In the `context` you have a key named `shelf.io.connection_info` where you will find all the information about the connection.

Comment: Exemple: final info = request.context['shelf.io.connection_info'] as HttpConnectionInfo?; final clientAddress = info?.remoteAddress.address;